# ¿Como ingresar varias variables a una base de datos?

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, android-sqlite, insert

Ayuda quiero poner varios datos en una base de datos y no se porque no se guardan :C

````
            registro.put("id",etid_string);
            registro.put("q",Q);
            registro.put("hora",hora);
            registro.put("dia",dia);
            registro.put("mes",mes);
            registro.put("año",año);
            BaseDeDatos.insert("vertedores", null, registro);
            BaseDeDatos.execSQL("INSERT INTO vertedores(id,q,hora,dia,mes,año) VALUES (etid_string,Q,hora,dia,mes,año)");
            BaseDeDatos.close();```
````

Comment: Por cierto ya habia declarado ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

Comment: Hola! Podrías agregar el código del BaseDeDatos.insert() y BaseDeDatos.execSQL :)